# is there a way to navigate in file system with comand line and using the arrow keys

Tags: command-line, keyboard, nautilus, filesystem, navigation

Sometimes I like to navigate direct in command line (without nautilus). But the need to use ls and then cd multiple times is uncomfortable. Is there some terminal app that automate this "ls cd" process and let us use the arrow keys to navigate select a directory to run the command "cd"????

Comment: I think, you already know about Bash file name completion (using the TAB key) and also about some terminal file managers like `mc`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, but you have to install an app. Here, I'd suggest the [n³ terminal program](https://github.com/jarun/nnn). You can install it with `sudo apt update && sudo apt install nnn`. To launch the program, type `nnn` into your terminal and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. You can have up to four current directories at once (so press <kbd>3</kbd> to go to the third one, for example). You navigate the directories with the arrow keys. Up/down switches what file is selected, the left arrow goes up in the directory tree (i.e., to the parent folder/closer to the root of the filesystem). The right arrow navigates into the selected directory (as does <kbd>Enter</kbd>). <kbd>Q</kbd> exits the program. You can get a list of keybinds by pressing <kbd>?</kbd>.

I personally prefer just using `cd`, and I find getting used to it is better, as sooner or later you will probobly have to use a device that just has the standard utilities (e.g., `cd`, `ls`, etc.), and no terminal file manager. There are other terminal file managers, too. Just search for "terminal file manager".